# Strip out all single quotes

Tags: php, wordpress, csv, quote

I am looking for the best way to strip single quotes as it keeps breaking my important.

so

> The image’s emotiveness enables

only comes through as

> The image

It breaks at the single quote ' .I need a good way to strip out the tags can someone help.

I have looked at stripslashes();

Whats the best way function to stripout , - £

any help please.

MANAGED TO FIX IT>

Thank you for your help people i manage to fix it using the following function.

> string utf8_encode ( string $data )

Cant figure out why it was coming out in that format from the database all i can think is it 6 years old website.

;)

Comment: What programming language / libraries are you working with? You might also add what you're *really* trying to do. It might be that you don't want to strip characters, rather you want to properly encode them?

Comment: hi charlie i am trying to insert a csv file into wordpress via the insert_post function, i am using php, everything works fine but it just seems to break at the follow characters it driving me crazy - £ ' thanks for the reply.

Comment: The respective function http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.1/wp-includes/post.php calls some sort of sanitizing functions. But it being wordpress, a lack of SQL escaping just seems the most likely explanation. Though for `£` it could just be the charset. (Try utf8_encode or _decode)

Comment: thanks for all the help guys this is an example off the data i am trying to import http://isdcsv.users35.interdns.co.uk/all.php

Comment: so basically i am trying to grab all the data form the above url and then insert it into a .csv then i am using csv importer plugin to insert posts into wordpress but it breaks on those annoying little quotes.

Comment: I am thinking it might be something to do with charset=utf-8 because i get an error when trying to save the csv. This file contains character in unicode format which will be lost if you save as ANSI encode file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% certain because PHP isn't my forte, but I think you need to look at something like [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php).  This will encode all the special characters properly.

Comment: It's for encoding special characters in URLs. I don't think this one can help to strip out single quotes.

Comment: *Some* kind of escaping has to happen. As I mentioned in a comment already, I don't think the OP wants to strip them out completely. I am not familiar with wordpress, but as someone else mentioned, SQL escaping is likely needed.

Comment: Yes, totally agree... I just said that urlencode() can't do what OP wants. But yes, you're absolutely right about escaping.

Answer (score 3):

**Note: This will remove all single quotes!**

```
str_replace("'", "", $your_string);
```

example:

```
$your_string = "The image’s emotiveness enables.";
echo str_replace("'", "", $your_string);
```

output

> The images emotiveness enables.

If you want to keep single quotes in string you should consider using real escape functions (recommended).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you really want is to encode the single quotes, not remove them. On the assumption that you are inserting into the MySQL database, look into `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to get rid of specific characters is using str_replace.

To remove all single quotes from a string:

```
$noQuotes = str_replace("'", '', $stringWithQuotes);
```

Comment: it weird little quotes like this $strip = str_replace('`', "'", $out);

Answer (score 1):

There is several ways, depending on what are you doing.

You could use [addslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) to escape all single / double quotes. You can unescape it with [stripslashes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) later.

If you are planning on saving those data into MySQL database, you should use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

If you want to output data on HTML page, use [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to convert all special characters into HTML entities.

The next way is to use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to remove all quotes, as few other people in this thread already mentioned.

Comment: hi this is how the data come out from the db http://isdcsv.users35.interdns.co.uk/all.php lots off question marks ???